# Are SQL stoplist words always ignored?

Tags: sql, stop-words

I'm using SQL server 2012 and SQL manager. Are words in the stoplist always ignored?

If my stoplist is blank I get:

```
select Count(*) from freetexttable(Document,[ContentsPlainText],'i') --> 1268
select Count(*) from freetexttable(Document,[ContentsPlainText],'a') --> 186
select Count(*) from freetexttable(Document,[ContentsPlainText],'av') --> 0
```

If my stoplist contains 'a', 'i', 'av' I get:

```
select Count(*) from freetexttable(Document,[ContentsPlainText],'i') --> 0
select Count(*) from freetexttable(Document,[ContentsPlainText],'a') --> 186
select Count(*) from freetexttable(Document,[ContentsPlainText],'av') --> 0
```

This gives:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM document WHERE ContentsPlainText LIKE '%i%' --> 1340
SELECT count(*) FROM document WHERE ContentsPlainText LIKE '%a%' --> 1338
SELECT count(*) FROM document WHERE ContentsPlainText LIKE '%av%' --> 1295
```

I would expect the first freetext search to return 'something' for all and the second 'none' for all. Instead 'i' behaves as i expect, whereas the other are constant at 0 or 186. Can't get this to work properly.

EDIT 1: If I try the same with 'er' I'm able to reduce the hits from 1100 to 1000 or so. Which is a third scenario.

EDIT 2: I got it to work somewhat now. By repopulating the table (I think that's what did it) I now reduce the hits on all searches if they are in the stoplist. However, on some searchwords I only reduce the amount of hits, but there are still more results than 0. Maybe the search conjugates the words etc before the stoplist is coming to action